# Convert json object to csv files and merge them using JSZip

Tags: javascript, jszip

I am using the below function to convert a JSON object to a CSV file and download it. This part is doing fine.

```
const JSONToCSVConvertor = (JSONData, ReportTitle, ShowLabel) => {
    //If JSONData is not an object then JSON.parse will parse the JSON string in an Object
    var arrData =
        typeof JSONData !== 'object' ? JSON.parse(JSONData) : JSONData;

    var CSV = '';

    //This condition will generate the Label/Header
    if (ShowLabel) {
        var row = '';

        //This loop will extract the label from 1st index of on array
        for (var index in arrData[0]) {
            //Now convert each value to string and comma-seprated
            row += index + ',';
        }

        row = row.slice(0, -1);

        //append Label row with line break
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    //1st loop is to extract each row
    for (var i = 0; i < arrData.length; i++) {
        var row = '';

        //2nd loop will extract each column and convert it in string comma-seprated
        for (var index in arrData[i]) {
            row += '"' + arrData[i][index] + '",';
        }

        row.slice(0, row.length - 1);

        //add a line break after each row
        CSV += row + '\r\n';
    }

    if (CSV === '') {
        alert('Invalid data');
        return;
    }

    //Generate a file name
    var fileName = '';
    //this will remove the blank-spaces from the title and replace it with an underscore
    fileName += ReportTitle.replace(/ /g, '_');

    //Initialize file format you want csv or xls
    var uri = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + escape(CSV);
    // generate a temp <a /> tag
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = uri;

    //set the visibility hidden so it will not effect on your web-layout
    link.style = 'visibility:hidden';
    link.download = fileName + '.csv';

    //this part will append the anchor tag and remove it after automatic click
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    // console.log('finish download one file');
};
```

Right now I am trying to create a zip file based on the JSON objects. I am planning to use the JSZip library.

```
     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
         zip.file('file' + i + '.csv', escape(CSV));
     }

     zip.generateAsync({ type: 'base64' }).then((base64) => {
         window.location = 'data:application/zip;base64,' + base64;
     });
```

`escape(CSV)` in the above code snippet is the proper CSV file format. This code snippet does not create a zip file and does not throw any error code. It only brings my current page to about:blank#blocked.

But if I change the second parameter of zip.file() to 'csv data', it works and gives me a zip file.

My solution is

1. to download the CSV files using the `JSONToCSVConvertor` function
2. using the JSZip library to read the CSV files from the local repository and zip them.

I think this way is not the best way to do it, because I have to download multiple CSV files before zipping them.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question I follow this article to solve my issue

https://huynvk.dev/blog/download-files-and-zip-them-in-your-browsers-using-javascript